# Iterate a dataframe through one row and every columnname and fill new dataframe for bkoeh-heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have read a csv-file using pd.read_csv and created a new dataframe with sample times in the first column and location names as following column names.
Now I would like to fill in the values from the csv_read according to sample time and location name.

read_csv dataframe (df):

```
Index   Location Description    ....   Sample Time          ...   Value

0       Location_1_100         ....   2018-12-13 00:30:00  ...    0.45

1       Location_1_101         ....   2018-12-13 00:30:00    ....  0.33
```

ready to fill dataframe (master):

```
Index   Sample Time            Location_1_100   Location_1_101   ...

0       2018-12-13 00:30:00   Value from df     Value from df

1       2018-12-13 01:00:00   Value from df     Value from df
```

```py
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(remove_bom('file.csv'), parse_dates=['Sample Time'])

df['Sample Time'] = df['Sample Time'].dt.round('30min')

sensoren = df.drop_duplicates('Location Description')

master = pd.DataFrame(data={'Sample Time':df['Sample Time']})
master = master.drop_duplicates()
master = master.reindex(columns=master.columns.tolist()+sensoren['Location Description'].tolist())

for ind, column in enumerate(master.columns[1:]):
    master[column][ind]=df.loc[(df['Location Description'] == column)&(df['Sample Time'] == master['Sample Time'][ind])
```

This code should fill the values from df in master, but it only fills the first Sample Time at the first Location, second sample time at second location etc.

I also tried some nested for-loops but as I am new to python I didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this code:

```
i=0
    #Put columns in list
    columns=master.columns.tolist()
    #Delete "Sample Time"
    del columns[0]
    #Remove strange indices
    master=master.reset_index(drop=True)
    #Iterate through columns
    for y in columns:
    #Iterate through times
        for x in master.loc[:,'Sample Time']: 
    #Check if a value was found (needed for iloc)
            if not ((df.loc[(df['Location Description'] == y)&(df['Sample Time'] == x), 'Value']).empty):
    #Copy value to master, if there are multiple values take the first
                master.loc[i,y]=(df.loc[(df['Location Description'] == y)&(df['Sample Time'] == x), 'Value']).iloc[0]
    #Delete used row in df to improve performance
            df=df.drop(df.index[(df['Location Description'] == y)&(df['Sample Time'] == x)])
            i+=1
    #Reset index when moving to next column
        i=0
```

It works, but I've got great performance issues.
It runs for hours and hours but won't get finished.